# Adobe Illustrator selection and scripting

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, illustrator-scripting

I want to ask two questions

1. I can select multiple objects, and after that, if I click one of the selected objects, last clicked one becomes "active" or "super selected." What is the name of this selection, I could not find.
2. How can I access this super selected object from Illustrator scripting? `Document.selection` just gives selection, and there is no `activeObject`.

I'm trying to develop a simple Illustrator script to make objects same size as the first one or super selected one with one click.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to acess this data in the documentation. The scripting API isnt actually a first class member of adobes development effort. So new features dont flow into it.

Time to go for the c++ . But even there you have severe limitations.

Comment: thank you. Do you know what this extra selection is called anyway?

Comment: @Erdogan Kurtur its called the "Key Object" in the align toolbox

Answer (score 0):

This is noted by Adobe official Illustrator developer team. In future update they will bring it sure.

For now You have to turn your algorithm or follow any other way for scripting.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Do you have a link for that note?

Comment: Been waiting for this for nearly 10 years now. To be honest not going to hold my breath. In general i dont believe what adobe says only what it does.